# Require() in REPL does not seem to work properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, read-eval-print-loop

**Problem:** I just started out in node.js and when using REPL to `require` a module, its function keeps showing undefined. Where did it go wrong?

Also, why does the `var s = require('./simple');` line result in an `undefined` response? I am using node v0.6.2

**simple.js**

```
var counts = 0;
exports.next = function() { counts++; }
```

**What I did in REPL**

```
> var s = require('./simple');
undefined
> s.next
[Function]
> s.next()
undefined
> s.next();
undefined
```

Comment: Are you starting the REPL in the same directory as the file?

Comment: @pradeek yes I typed `node` in the same directory as the file `simple.js`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is completely normal, since your function doesn't actually return anything it would return undefined by default. Try this `exports.next = function() {return counts++; }` you get the number before the addition.